# error in creating db in phpmyadmin xampp v3.2.1

Tags: phpmyadmin

> #1089 - Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique prefix keys---what is prefix key?

this error message is showing when try to save my table.
here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE `student`.`stud_detail` ( `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `first_name` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL , `last_name` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL , `marks` INT(100) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`ID`(100)) ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Was this SQL generated by phpMyAdmin? Are you using the phpMyAdmin "Add index" dialog?

Comment: yes i am using phpMyAdmin and add index...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Add index dialog box so I can see exactly what it looks like when you're creating the key?

Answer (score 2):

I get the same error each time I create a table with an auto increment field. I've got no explanation for it but this is how I deal with it:

1- create a table without AI(auto increment) or primary

2- access the table, go to "structure" tab then click on "change" on the field you want to set as primary or AI

3- set the AI or primary then save changes

Answer (score 0):

1. First Fall Create table Without Primary key and Auto_increment
2. After create table then Define Primary key
3. last step define Auto_increment

Thank You